# android.widget.Switch cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton

Tags: android, android-switch, android-togglebutton

I got these simple lines of code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
(...)
   public void VehicleDeleteModus(View v){
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
   (...)
   }
}
```

XML:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="VehicleDeleteModus"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:text="Delete-Modus"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

The app compiles and gets installed on my Galaxy Nexus without any errors. However, I get this exception immediately after pressing the switch (on/off-slider):

> android.widget.switch cannot be cast to android.widget.togglebutton

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean convert to `CompoundButton` not `ToggleButton`. Casting `Dog` to `Cat` is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Even though [`Switch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) and [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) are [`CompoundButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html), `Switch` is not a `ToggleButton`. Each one cannot be used interchangeably.

```
         CompoundButton
                |
    +-----------+----------+
    |                      |
 Switch               ToggleButton
```

Try changing the casting to `(CompoundButton)` (for general case) or `(Switch)` (specific, better) instead.

```
public void VehicleDeleteModus(View v){
    boolean on = ((Switch) v).isChecked();
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wanting to cast to a toggle button? Just keep using the switch object. You just have to implement an event listener, just like you would for a button click.Then get the checked status from the boolean parameter.

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    //get boolean value from parameter.

    boolean on = isChecked;
    }
});
```